# Is $\|M^s\|\leq \|M\|^s$ for every $s\in \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $M$ be a self-adjoint operator on a complex Hilbert space $H$.

> Let $s\in \mathbb{R}$. Is
> $$\|M^s\|\leq \|M\|^s\;?$$

Since $M$ is selfadjoint, then by the Spectral Theorem we have
$$
M^s=\int_{\sigma(M)}\lambda^s\,dE(\lambda).
$$
Then
$$
\|M^s\|\leq\int_{\sigma(M)}|\lambda|^s\,\|dE(\lambda)\|.
$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1680287/norm-of-a-self-adjoint-operator

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Thanks for the link but it is not related to my question

Comment: Consider $s=-1$.  The non-invertible operator $M$ could well have $\|M\| = 1$, yielding $\infty \le 1$.

Comment: @GEdgar May be the result holds only if $s\in [0,1]$?

Comment: The spectral projections $E(\lambda)$ likely satisfy $\|E(\lambda_2) - E(\lambda_1)\| = 1$ for all $\lambda_1  < \lambda_2$, so $\|dE(\lambda)\|$ is not a useful measure.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $$M = \pmatrix{2 & 0 \\ 0 & 3}, \quad M^{-1} = \pmatrix{\frac12 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac13}$$
so $\|M\| = 3$ and $\|M^{-1}\| = \frac12$ so
$$\|M^{-1}\| \le \|M\|^{-1}$$
yields $\frac12 \le \frac13$ which is not true.

For positive $s > 0$ the claim is true since the function $x \mapsto x^s$ is continuous and increasing so
$$\|M^s\| = \max_{\lambda \in \sigma(M^s)}|\lambda| = \max_{\lambda\in\sigma(M)}|\lambda^s| = \max_{\lambda\in\sigma(M)}|\lambda|^s = \left(\max_{\lambda\in\sigma(M)}|\lambda|\right)^s = \|M\|^s$$
so even equality holds.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is trivial that when $M$ is selfadjoint then so is $M^s$ with $s$ real?

Comment: @Schüler Yes, a normal operator $A$ is self-adjoint if and only if $\sigma(A) \subseteq \Bbb{R}$. Since $M$ is self-adjoint, we have $\sigma(M)\subseteq \Bbb{R}$ so $$\sigma(M^s) = \sigma(M)^s \subseteq \Bbb{R}^s \subseteq \Bbb{R}$$
and $M^s$ is normal by definition so $M^s$ is self-adjoint.